Can i scale a tube without changing its wall thickness?
So I have a tube and I wanted to make many copies with different diameters, but I want to keep its wall thickness, bevels etc. Scalling down makes everything proportionally smaller, so it doesn’t work… Any suggestions?


Start with a tube model that has not been solidified, and put a Solidify modifier on it without applying. Then, make your duplicates, scale them as desired, and apply the scale (NOT visual geometry to mesh). With scale applied to the base geometry, the modifier(s) should be procedurally adding the same thickness to all of them.
